# ramdajs: locating items with an inner array that satisfies a spec

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Given a structure like this:

```
[
  {
    documentType: { id: 4001 }
    correspondence: [ { id: 1000 }, { id: 1010 } ]
  },
  {
    documentType: { id: 102 }
    correspondence: [ { id: 1000 } ]
  },
  {
    documentType: { id: 101 }
    correspondence: [ { id: 1001 } ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to use ramda to find the indexes of the array where the inner correspondence array contains 1000.

I have tried this:

```
R.filter(R.where({ correspondence: R.any(R.where({ id: 1000 }))}))(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll want a slight tweak to your predicate function, changing the inner `R.where` to `R.propEq` to allow comparison against a constant value rather than a function:

```
const pred = R.where({ correspondence: R.any(R.propEq('id', 1000))})
```

Then I have two examples of how you could approach this, both making use of `R.addIndex` to capture the index:

One using `R.reduce` to build up a list while testing each element:

```
const reduceWithIdx = R.addIndex(R.reduce)
const fn = reduceWithIdx((acc, x, i) => pred(x) ? R.append(i, acc) : acc, [])

fn(data) //=> [0, 1]
```

The second using `R.map` to embed the index in each element before filtering:

```
const mapWithIdx = R.addIndex(R.map)

const fn = R.pipe(
  mapWithIdx(R.flip(R.assoc('idx'))),
  R.filter(pred),
  R.map(R.prop('idx'))
)

fn(data) //=> [0, 1]
```